Is the sentence "You have a parcel arrived" grammatically corrrect?
I came across an online debate about whether this sentence is correct. Of course, it is colloquially understandable, but there have been arguments that since 'arrived' is intransitive, it cannot be placed at the end. So the correct version would be either "you have a parcel that has arrived" or "you have an arrived parcel". What do you think about this?

Almost any past participle can be used adjectivally, so in principle both "You have a parcel arrived" and "You have an arrived parcel" are syntactically "valid". But they're both hopelessly non-idiomatic, so just forget about them.

A parcel has arrived for you.  or A parcel for you has arrived. or You have a parcel arriving (if tracking says it is on the way and out for delivery).  I think in some dialects the past participle might also be  used there after it has arrived, but not in standard English.


"A parcel has arrived for you":.
This is the most natural choice in everyday English. It conveys the message clearly and concisely. The focus is on the event of the parcel arriving.
"You have a parcel that has arrived":.
This is grammatically correct but the meaning is  the person has the parcel and it has arrived. It is less natural than the first sentence.
"You have a parcel arrived":


Incorrect because:
Arrived is intransitive and cannot function as a direct object modifier here.
It’s an ungrammatical condensation of "You have a parcel that has arrived."


"You have an arrived parcel":
Technically grammatical, but unnatural.
"Arrived" is rarely used as an adjective in English. Instead, adjectives like delivered, received, or incoming would be more appropriate.


I can't imagine any context where OP's You have a parcel arrived would sound natural, but I have no problem with "There's a parcel arrived,” Charles informed her, while pointing to a package on his desk... It seems existential there's is inherently more accommodating. But using it as a "fronted" adjective is definitely the least acceptable variation.

@James Mathai, Thanks for the detailed answer, however, as a non-native speaker, I wonder why it is an ungrammatical condensation of "You have a parcel that has arrived." Can we just not remove relative pronoun and the auxialiary?

@Yunus  "You have a parcel that has arrived". We are assuming that the person doesn't know that the parcel has arrived. Removing relative clause and the auxiliary "You have a parcel arrived" is incorrect because arrived cannot function as an adjective.
